# Express App Serving Unwanted Static Files

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, single-page-application

I have a react app that is served by express. The entire app is included in public/index.html.

Right now my server.js looks like this:

```
  1 const express = require('express');
  2 const path = require('path');
  3 const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
  4 const app = express();
  5
  6 // the __dirname is the current directory from where the script is running
  7 app.use(express.static(__dirname));
  8
  9 app.get('*', (req, res) => {
 10   res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/index.html'));
 11 });
 12
 13 app.listen(port);
```

However, somehow, files like package.json and /.ssh/known_hosts are being served, things that obviously shouldn't be avaialible.

I'm not sure why `app.get('*', (req, res)...` isn't catching all requests, and why `app.use(express.static(__dirname));` seems to be the only configuration that allows my app to server ANY static files.

I haven't had any luck with `app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/public'));` or

`app.use( '/', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));`

or anything else I can find.

EDIT---

My project directory looks like:

```
/myproject
    package.json
    server.js
    /public
        index.html
```

I want ALL requests to simply serve index.html

What I'm still not understanding is why

`app.use('*', express.static(path.resolve(__dirname,'/public/index.html')));`

does not serve anything.

Also, why in the above example, res.sendFile() does nothing without first having called express.static(). If I delete line 7, then nothing is served.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, never ever do this:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname));
```

in your main server directory.  That exposes ALL your server files to be viewed.

When using `express.static()` to serve a whole directory, you should create a directory that contains ONLY files intended for public consumption and then point `express.static()` at that.

> I'm not sure why app.get('*', (req, res)... isn't catching all requests

Because that `app.get('*', ...)` is AFTER your `express.static()` so if the `express.static()` finds a matching file, the `app.get('*', ...)` never even sees the request.  It's already handled and routing doesn't continue any more.

---

As always with `express.static()` to advise on exactly what you should do, we need to know the precise configuration you have.  Where are the public files in your file system relative to your main server directory and what URLs are you intending to use in the client to refer to those publicly available files.

---

Here's a theoretical example (since you haven't provided your specifics):

Let's suppose you have files like this:

```
/myproject
   app.js
   /public
       main.css
```

And, suppose you want to be able to use `/main.css` as the URL from the client.  For that, you would just do this from within app.js:

```
 app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));
```

In this first example, where you're serving these static files at the top level path, then you have to make sure there are no naming conflicts between these top level resources and any actual routes you want to serve.

If you wanted the client-side URLs to be `/assets/main.css`, then you would do this:

```
 app.use("/assets", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));
```

In this example, you must make sure that the `/public` sub-directory (and any sub-directories it might have) contains only files intended to be publicly accessible.

Adding a path to the public URL such as `/assets` removes the chance of a naming conflict between your static assets and your top level routes.  This can be a good thing because in any multi-person project, it's not uncommon that the person working on the static assets (like CSS files) is different than the person working on server routes so the two main not be directly aware of what names each other is using.  In a single person project, you would certainly just keep it all in your head and avoid accidental naming conflicts that way.

---

FYI, my preference for folder organization is more like this:

```
/myproject
   /server
       app.js
   /public
       main.css
```

Where it's 100% obvious which are server files and which are public files.  Then, to serve the public files from within app.js with a URL of `/assets/main.css`, I'd do this:

```
app.use("/assets", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "../public")));
```

---

From your comments:

> I just want to serve public/index.html for all ('*') GET requests. All other data comes from separate apis. it seems that res.sendFile() doesn't work without first using express.static. The above code resides in server.js

If all you want to do is to serve `public/index.html` for all requests (where `public` is a sub-directory below where `app.js` is located), then remove the `express.static()` middleware entirely.

Just use this from app.js:

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public/index.html'));
 });
```

Comment: I just want to serve public/index.html for all ('*') GET requests. All other data comes from separate apis. it seems that res.sendFile() doesn't work without first using express.static. The above code resides in server.js

Comment: @C-RAD - What are you using `express.static()` for then?  If all you want to do is to serve `public/index.html` for ALL incoming requests, then remove `express.static()`.  It's pointless for that task.  See what I added to the end of my answer for more specifics.

Comment: the `app.get('*', ...` matcher doesn't work without it. In the above example, all requests not caught by line 7 are caught by line 9, but if I delete line 7, then the application serves nothing at all.

Comment: Or I should say, it's the res.sendFile() that seems not to work without having the prior use of express.static. The routes seem to be matching correctly

Comment: @C-RAD - `res.sendFile()` has absolutely nothing to do with `express.static()`.  I suspect your `res.sendFile()` did not work properly and the `express.static()` was sending the file for you.

Comment: @C-RAD - Also, note my suggestion at the end of my answer uses `path.join()`, not `path.resolve()` like you were using.

Comment: feel free to try the first code example. I can hit `localhost:8080/foobar` and it will serve me public/index.html. When I try to delete line 7 (`app.use(express.static(__dirname));`) for security reasons, however that functionality stops working.

Comment: @C-RAD - Because your `res.sendFile()` code is wrong and not working.   That has nothing to do with `express.static()`. When you have the `express.static()` it finds the desired file and sends it for you and your code never gets to the `res.sendFile()`.  That just covers up a wrong `res.sendFile()` route.  You need to fix the `res.sendFile()` route and  remove the `express.static()` route. Sorry, but I can't see your exact code or debug it for you.  Can only explain things here and show you proper working examples.

Comment: I *know* that res.sendFile() is working, because if I delete it, I can no longer get index.js from localhost:8080/foobar. I can put a console.log after line 9 and prove that it hits res.sendFile() as well. The problem is that express.static() is not idempotent so even though my requests aren't matching on line 7, when they are served on line 10, they are dependent on express.static having been called correctly. I got all of this from here if you would like to give it a try: https://dev.to/nburgess/creating-a-react-app-with-react-router-and-an-express-backend-33l3. Thanks 4 taking interest btw.

Comment: @C-RAD - I would have to see your exact code that behaves that way and the exact directory hierarchy that shows where all relevant files are located and know exactly which URLs you are testing.  What you have in your question doesn't do that.  I will be out for the next couple of hours.  As best I know `express.static()` is idempotent.  It just looks for a match and if one isn't found, either continues routing by calling `next()` (default behavior) or sends a 404 (if option is set to do that).

Comment: I'll try to make a mini-example and push it.

Comment: @C-RAD - I'm wondering if your `index.html` has references to static resources in it (CSS files, script tags, images, etc...) that are what is requiring the `express.static()`.

Comment: @ jfriend00 I'm thinking you're right. It was pulling in `dist/bundle.js` in another request, which must have been matching `express.static()`. So I think I was confused about which requests were matching which routes. I'll try to confirm and clean this up a bit

Answer (score 0):

`app.use(express.static(__dirname));` will make your app insecure.
Always print out the URLs in the console like `path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/index.html')` to find out if there is something wrong in it. Seems aiming to the root directory for static files makes problem. Put them in the conventional public directory then try it out again

Answer (score -1):

remove `app.use(express.static(__dirname));`

as that tells express to load all files that exist